# Can suddenly no longer connect to VPN host after reboot?

Tags: vpn, windows, pptp

I've had a solid connection to my home VPN server (windows 2012) from my office (windows 8.1) for days over PPTP and have had no issues.

This morning, I had to hard-shutdown my server due to an unrelated issue and reboot it. The issue is, on my office PC, I can suddenly no longer connect to it. It just hangs on "connecting" and eventually times out. IP and other settings have stayed the same. I have GRE and port 1723 forward in the firewall.

I'm not too advanced with VPN, so I'm not sure exactly what else it could be. Other devices outside of my network can connect just fine. I don't believe anything on the office network changed because it was working fine up until I rebooted my home server. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that RA manager is running, and double check that the local network still allows access too it.. ie telnet yourhomeip:1723
if that fails something on your local office network changed.

Comment: Whenever I telnet to it, it says it can't connect on port 23. It says this for every port I use. Not sure what this means.

Comment: sorry that was my typo use telnet myhomeip 1723 use a space instead of the colon.